# How to filter observable data from api?

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs-observables

```
 public rows$: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rows$ = this.StockService.findAll();
  }
  searchData(event: any) {
    let term: string = event.target.value;
    console.log(term);
     this.rows$.pipe(
      map((items) =>
        items.filter(
          (item) =>
            item.prdoct_code=== term ||
            item.product_name === term ||
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

I want to add a search for ngx datatable, this is how I code, but after searching, ngoninit works and instead of filtered data, all products come and none appear in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply expressing `this.rows$.pipe(...)` does not affect the original observable, it defines a new one.

In your case, you need to define `rows$` to be an observable that depends on 2 different sources: the stock service results (`items`) and the search term (`term`).  So, you need a way to have your search term be observable.  We can use a -[`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) for this:

```js
private term$  = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
private items$ = this.StockService.findAll();

public rows$: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest([this.items$, this.term$]).pipe(
  map(([items, term]) => items.filter(
     (item) =>
       term === '' ||
       item.prdoct_code === term ||
       item.product_name === term
  ))
);
  
searchData(event: any) {
  const term: string = event.target.value;
  this.term$.next(term);
}
```

The line `private term$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('')` defines a subject that emits an initial value of empty string `''`.  We can push values through the subject by calling its `.next()` method and passing a value.

We use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to define a single observable with multiple sources.  `combineLatest` will emit the most recent value from each source whenever any of the sources emit a value. So, whenever your `searchData()` method is called, the most recen values of `list` and `term` will be emitted and pass through the filter logic in the `.pipe(map(...))`.

Comment: this.searchTerm$.next(term);   will this line be correct or not $term and                          
               <ngx-datatable
              [rows]="rows$ | async"
              [rowHeight]="60"

Comment: term === ' ' >>>> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.

Comment: how can I get results containing instead of results that are equal (example mysql like) ?